# python memory leak using wxPython

Tags: python, debugging, memory, wxpython, memory-leaks

I recently realised, that my program have a memory leak, it's small, but either, I think it shouldn't be there at all.

Part which causes memory leak actually creates a new `wx.Panel` and add's it to interface using `wx.WindowSplitter` and then removes panel and un
splits window.

```
self.getAction(self, event):
    if self.lastEdit[0] != None:
        if self.lastEdit[4] == STATEMENT:
            dialog = EditStatement(self.API.editorSplitter,
                    self.API, self.lastEdit, self.statementUpdateClbk)
        elif self.lastEdit[4] == CONDITION:
            dialog = EditCondition(self.API.editorSplitter,
                    self.API, self.lastEdit, self.conditionUpdateClbk)
    # Show or hide split window
    self.splitEditor(dialog)

def splitEditor(self, editPanel):
    self.API.editorSplitter.Unsplit()
    if self.lastPanel != None:
        self.lastPanel.DissociateHandle()
        self.lastPanel.DestroyChildren()
        self.lastPanel.Destroy()
    self.lastPanel = editPanel
    if editPanel != None:
        self.API.editorSplitter.SplitVertically(self.API.tabManager,  
                                           editPanel, -305)
```

Note that `EditStatement` un `EditCondition` is `wx.Panel` clases mentioned before. Calling `getAction()` in cycle randomly increases memory usage, the weirdest thing is, that at some iterations there is no change, at some iterations used memory even falls a bit, but at most iterations used memory grows. Here is some output of debug, made using `gc` module wrapper.

Used code to test:

```
def cycler(self):
    while True:
        self.getAction(None) #Show window
        wx.YieldIfNeeded()
        self.mem() # prints memory information
        self.splitEditor(None) #Hide window
        wx.YieldIfNeeded()
        self.mem() # prints memory information
```

Output is as follows:

> ```
> Window action -  Action      Object          Count
>
> Create Window -  Added    StaticText  10
> Create Window -  Changed  dict    +1
> Create Window -  Added    GridBagSizer    1
> Create Window -  Changed  list    +2
> Create Window -  Added    CheckBox    4
> Create Window -  Changed  ComboBox    +6
> Create Window -  Added    EditStatement   1
> Create Window -  Changed  BoxSizer    +1
> Create Window -  Changed  instancemethod  +15
>
> Create Window -  Count = 25453
> Create Window -  Memory(rss): 42528
>
> Destroy Window -  Changed dict    -1
> Destroy Window -  Changed list    -2
> Destroy Window -  Changed ComboBox    -6
> Destroy Window -  Changed BoxSizer    -1
> Destroy Window -  Changed instancemethod  -15
> Destroy Window -  Deleted StaticText  10
> Destroy Window -  Deleted GridBagSizer    1
> Destroy Window -  Deleted CheckBox    4
> Destroy Window -  Deleted EditStatement   1
>
> Destroy Window -  Count = 25412
> Destroy Window -  Memory(rss): 42528
>
> Create Window -  Added    StaticText  10
> Create Window -  Changed  dict    +1
> Create Window -  Added    GridBagSizer    1
> Create Window -  Changed  list    +2
> Create Window -  Added    CheckBox    4
> Create Window -  Changed  ComboBox    +6
> Create Window -  Added    EditStatement   1
> Create Window -  Changed  BoxSizer    +1
> Create Window -  Changed  instancemethod  +15
>
> Create Window -  Count = 25453
> Create Window -  Memory(rss): 42536
>
> Destroy Window -  Changed dict    -1
> Destroy Window -  Changed list    -2
> Destroy Window -  Changed ComboBox    -6
> Destroy Window -  Changed BoxSizer    -1
> Destroy Window -  Changed instancemethod  -15
> Destroy Window -  Deleted StaticText  10
> Destroy Window -  Deleted GridBagSizer    1
> Destroy Window -  Deleted CheckBox    4
> Destroy Window -  Deleted EditStatement   1
>
> Destroy Window -  Count = 25412
> Destroy Window -  Memory(rss): 42540
>
> Create Window -  Added    StaticText  10
> Create Window -  Changed  dict    +1
> Create Window -  Added    GridBagSizer    1
> Create Window -  Changed  list    +2
> Create Window -  Added    CheckBox    4
> Create Window -  Changed  ComboBox    +6
> Create Window -  Added    EditStatement   1
> Create Window -  Changed  BoxSizer    +1
> Create Window -  Changed  instancemethod  +15
>
> Create Window -  Count = 25453
> Create Window -  Memory(rss): 42552
>
> Destroy Window -  Changed dict    -1
> Destroy Window -  Changed list    -2
> Destroy Window -  Changed ComboBox    -6
> Destroy Window -  Changed BoxSizer    -1
> Destroy Window -  Changed instancemethod  -15
> Destroy Window -  Deleted StaticText  10
> Destroy Window -  Deleted GridBagSizer    1
> Destroy Window -  Deleted CheckBox    4
> Destroy Window -  Deleted EditStatement   1
>
> Destroy Window -  Count = 25412
> Destroy Window -  Memory(rss): 42556
>
> Create Window -  Added    StaticText  10
> Create Window -  Changed  dict    +1
> Create Window -  Added    GridBagSizer    1
> Create Window -  Changed  list    +2
> Create Window -  Added    CheckBox    4
> Create Window -  Changed  ComboBox    +6
> Create Window -  Added    EditStatement   1
> Create Window -  Changed  BoxSizer    +1
> Create Window -  Changed  instancemethod  +15
>
> Create Window -  Count = 25453
> Create Window -  Memory(rss): 42576
> ```

As You can see, used memory is increasing, but object count doesn't change after creation and deletion, I just don't understand what possibly can create such a memory leak. Any Ideas would be appreciated. In 45 minutes memory usage had grown from `~ 20 MB` to `~ 500 MB`.

P.S. If anyone is interested, source code of created Panels can be found at: [EditStatement](https://code.google.com/p/mansos/source/browse/trunk/tools/IDE/src/edit_statement.py) [EditCondition](https://code.google.com/p/mansos/source/browse/trunk/tools/IDE/src/edit_condition.py)

P.S.S. I'm not sure, but I tend to think it's wx.Python bug, something with `wx.SplitterWindow`

Comment: Are you able to create as small as possible complete runnable code which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Fenikso No, I just tried, but simply flickering Panel does not seem to do the trick. But I diged a bit into my problem and it seems to me, that memory is leaking in some other thread, which leads me to thinking, because I don't use threading in this part of app and I'm sure that no other thread is running at the time, only exception I can think is if wx uses threads, which I doubt, but I haven't checked.

Comment: If the object count does not change it sounds like a bug in wxWidgets implementation to me. But without isolating the problem there is probably no way how to report it. What is your wxPython version? Have you tried another one?